# Encrypt a portion of a script?

Tags: php, encryption

Is it possible to just encrypt a portion of a full php script?

For example: Just encrypt the following, but leave the rest of the script non-ecrypted.

```
function getTimeStamp() {
    return time();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but it would be useless. Please expand a little about your situation and what you want to achieve.

Comment: AFAIK you would have to make another file with all the functions you want to encrypt, encode or w/e then use zend or any other program that can obfuscate your code, dont think there is any other safe option for php even the tools out there such as zend are already broke in.

Comment: When you say encryption, you seem to mean obfuscation:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code

Answer (score 0):

No.  If you provide more information about what you are trying to do SO may be able to give you alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently a way where you're able to encrypt sections of a PHP script in a manner where it's undecodable. However, there is multiple ways to do so in a way which can be decoded, but would be slightly hard for basic users.

Here's what your provided code would look like in a small encrypted manner that works in PHP:

`$a='H';
$b='o';
eval(base64_decode("ZnVuY3Rpb24gZ2V0VGltZVN0YW1wKCkgew0KICAgI".($a)."Jld".$a."VybiB0aW1lKCk7DQp9DQ".$b."="));`

Try it. I did it by encoding your code in BASE64 and then changing parts of the Base64 string into variables. If you deeply tie in the code with the system, it makes it harder to decode. eval() runs code within text.